# Apache and PHP write permission?

Tags: apache-2.2, file-permissions

I have a php script that writes to a file.
But when I try to actually write to the file I get permission denied.
How can I tell what user name I need to add to the file permission in order for the php to write to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell what user name I need
>   to add to the file permission in order
>   for the php to write to it?

```
ps axu|grep apache|grep -v grep
```

Comment: I gives me `www-data`... So I just add this user to the group or something liek that? Is that a good solution, or does PHP provides me with something better?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to PHP, this is a general server issue (and would belong to serverfault.com). It may be solved in many different ways: giving the file to the user www-data is the most straightforward one, though I can't know if it's the best one for you (unless you give us much more detail).

Comment: There aren't any more details... I guess I'll go with the straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

whatever the file is, or directory for that matter, if apache needs to write to it, it needs to be owned by `apache`, `httpd`, `www-data`, or whatever the user apache is running under on your server. you said in a response that it is `www-data`, so as root, you should do `chown www-data filename` to change ownership.

i would strongly recommend against changing the permissions to 777, simply because having world readable/writable files and directories on your server can pose some security risks.

ultimately, i would configure your script to write to a set path, then change the ownership of that path to `www-data` so future files can be created there if need be, without your interaction being required.

this poses it's own risks, too, as a compromised script can then write and potentially execute whatever it wants from that directory.

as much of a pain as it may be, doing it file by file is less risky.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to just CHMOD the file to 777, assuming you're running on a Unix platform. May not be the most secure thing ever, must gets the job done reliably. I'm sure others will have a better solution though!

Comment: -1 not only this might be insecure, but it is not an actual answer to his question either (though I admit it could be considered some sort of workaround).

Comment: I gave you a +1 to even you up to a zero, for attempting to help. Your solution is insecure and since this is no longer one of my old high school projects I can't accept it. :)