# Write permissions on uploaded files - Linux, Apache, PHP

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, debian, permissions

I am working on a PHP script that transfers files using FTP functions. It has always worked on my production server (which is a hosting service). The development server I have just setup (I am a novice to servers) is Debian Lenny with Apache2, PHP5, and MySQL5.

The file transfer works correctly, but once the file has been written to the server, it has permissions of 600. This makes it impossible for me to view the file (JPEG) in the web browser, as permission is denied. I have scoured the internet and even broken my server installation and reinstalled it trying to figure this out (which has been fun, nonetheless!).

I know it is unwise to set `777` permissions on public accessible files, but even that will not solve the problem. The only thing that works is if I `chmod 777 thefile.jpg` *after* it has been transferred, which is not a working solution.

I tried changing the owner of my site files to `www-data` per [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/142456/apache-and-php-write-permission), but that also does not work.

My user is `mike`, and it still does not work whether the owner of the files is `mike` or `root`.

Would somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks! And, of course, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more related to your ftp server configuration, and not so much to apache. which server are you using for ftp? i believe vsftpd is the default ftp server for Debian Lenny, the options you might need to look at in your `vsftpd.conf` file are: `chown_upload_mode` and `file_open_mode`

the default for `chown_upload_mode` is `0600` which makes me think that might be what you need to set, and then restart your FTPd and try again.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense! Yes, I installed vsftpd so that I could transfer files from my workstation to the server. I'm looking at it now...

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to try and use the same FTP application that my hosting service uses?

Comment: you will want to set `chown_upload_mode` and `file_open_mode` to `644` which allows read/write to the owner, read to group, and read to world. permissions work like this: 1 = execute, 2 = write, 4 = read. 7 = read/write/execute, and so on.

Comment: i don't know, but whatever you use to send files to your web server, you'll need to look at the `umask` and permissions options in the configuration. also, most FTP clients will allow you to set permissions on files you have uploaded, so check the settings of your ftp client as well.

Comment: I ended up having internet connection difficulties with Debian and finally reinstalled Ubuntu 10.04 Server Edition. The internet problem was resolved. I started everything over and ended up only uncommenting `write_enable=YES` and `local_umask=022` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`. This allows my PHP FTP script to transfer files with permissions of `0644`. This allows my other scripts to actually be able to read the images for displaying them in the browser. Thank-you for pointing me towards `vsftpd.conf`, as that was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Apache is not configured to serve files out of the directory that the file is being saved to. You need to ensure there is a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) directive in you Apache configuration that permits access to the directory that the file is in. For example:

```
<Directory "/home/mike/uploads">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also the www-data user needs to have permission to traverse the directory tree leading to the directory. E.g. if the file is at `/home/mike/uploads` then the `home`, `mike` and `uploads` must have execute permisson allowed for other users.

Comment: I added the Directory directive that you shared to `apache2.conf`. Then I set the permissions for each of these directories: `/var/www/test/images` to `755`. But the problem still exists. Did I add the correct directory directive?

Comment: this did not work for my problem, but thanks for your help. I am still so new to this that this could very well be another solution for my problem and I don't even know it! If anything, it helped me dive a little deeper into Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. I would still like to know if this is an okay solution or not.

**Apache User and Group**

I changed `User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}` to `User mike` and `Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}` to `Group www-data`, then I restarted apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

**PHP5 Owner**

Next, I changed owner from `root` to `mike` on `/var/lib/php5` by:

```
chown -R mike /var/lib/php5
```

**Owner, Group, and Permissions for public folder**

Following [this article](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/9/18/apache-virtual-hosts-permissions), I did the following:

Added owner 'mike' to the www-data group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data mike
```

Changed the group for `/var/www` to `www-data`:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
```

Then, I changed permissions for `/var/www`:

```
sudo chmod -R 2750 /var/www
```

And, I did the following to the upload directory

```
sudo chmod -R 2770 /var/www/test/images
```

**Tried this...**

I originally added @Wes suggestion (below) to `apache2.conf`, but removed it after doing the above, which works. (Adding or removing this did not seem to affect anything):

```
<Directory "/var/www">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**But...**

The JPEG image files, after being transfered to the server via the PHP script, still have permissions of `-rw-------`, but I am able to view them from the web browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: it might work, but it is highly inadvisable. running a system service as a trusted user `mike` is not a very good idea, and changing ownership, recursively no less, of a system directory to `mike` is also not a great idea. you could look into implementing `suphp` or a similar product http://www.suphp.org/Home.html, `suphp` allows php scripts to run as a user, in this case `mike` allowing you to do what you want. `sudo chmod -R 2750 /var/www` makes me wish i was there to stop you... for what you want, files should be `644`

Comment: and i'm not saying `sudo chmod -R 2644 /var/www` would have been a solution either, a recursive `chmod` like that is just... disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @cpbills I'm cleaning up some of the stuff I did. Any comments about how I changed `User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}` and `Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}` ?

Comment: you would change that in your apache configuration, and i would keep it as `www-data` and `www-data`